# Lexical environment rules seem to contradict non-primitive data types rules in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, syntax

A function is an object, it is a non-primitive data type accessed via a link. When we assign a function to two different variables, it is expected that when we change a data stored inside the function, for example a variable's value, in one of the variables to which we assigned the function, it should change in the both variables to which the function has been assigned.

However, it is not the case when a lexical environment is changed for one of the variables to which the same function was assigned. In this case, the changed data changes only for the lexical environment of the function stored in the variable against which the change was implemented.

At the moment, I am not able to logically explain this. How it is possible that the following code keeps providing the outcome with no change for messenger1?

```js
const createMessenger = () => {
  let greeting = 'hi, buddy!';

  function sendMessage(name) {
    const sender = 'your master!';
    console.log(`${name}, ${greeting} It is ${sender}`);
  }

  function setGreeting(text) {
    greeting = text;
  }

  return {
    sendMessage,
    setGreeting,
  }
}

const messenger1 = createMessenger();
messenger1.sendMessage('Leonardo');

const messenger2 = createMessenger();
messenger2.sendMessage('Michelangelo');

messenger1.setGreeting('hiya!!!');
messenger1.sendMessage('Rafael');

messenger2.sendMessage('Donatello');
messenger1.sendMessage('Splinter');
```

Console results:

```
Leonardo, hi, buddy! It is your master!
Michelangelo, hi, buddy! It is your master!
Rafael, hiya!!! It is your master!
Donatello, hi, buddy! It is your master!
plinter, hiya!!! It is your master!
```

Comment: What's the issue you're facing?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, **tell other readers what the expected behavior should be**. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: "*When we assign a function to two different variables, it is expected that when we change a data stored inside the function, for example a variable's value, in one of the variables to which we assigned the function, it should change in the both variables to which the function has been assigned.*" That is correct. You simply don't have *one* object assigned, you have two different objects.

Comment: "*data stored inside the function, for example a variable's value*" - you might be confusing variables that are part of the lexical environment over which a function closes with variables that are created when a function is called.

Comment: Do you realise that there are 5 distinct function objects in your example?

Answer (score 0):

You could think of variable bindings as being created whenever the line that initializes the variable runs. For example, whenever

```
let greeting =
```

runs, a new `greeting` identifier is created.

In your code, every time you call `createMessenger`, the line `let greeting` runs again, creating a new `greeting` for that invocation. So when you do

```
const messenger1 = createMessenger();
const messenger2 = createMessenger();
```

You now have two separate `greeting` bindings - one inside the closure that `messenger1` has a reference to, and one inside the closure that `messenger2` has a reference to.

The behavior that you're describing here:

> When we assign a function to two different variables, it is expected that when we change a data stored inside the function, for example a variable's value, in one of the variables to which we assigned the function, it should change in the both variables to which the function has been assigned.

is only true when the *same* value is assigned to both variables, in which case a change to something inside one would indeed be visible in both. If you called `createMessanger` only once, and assigned the resulting object to two separate variables, you'd see the behavior you're expecting.

```js
const createMessenger = () => {
  let greeting = 'hi, buddy!';
  function sendMessage(name) {
    const sender = 'your master!';
    console.log(`${name}, ${greeting} It is ${sender}`);
  }
  function setGreeting(text) {
    greeting = text;
  }
  return {
    sendMessage,
    setGreeting,
  }

}

const messenger1 = createMessenger();
const messenger2 = messenger1;
messenger1.setGreeting('Greeting 1');
messenger2.sendMessage('Message 2');
```

Above, `const messenger2 = messenger1;` means that both messanger variables hold a reference to the *same object*.

In contrast, doing

```
const messenger1 = createMessenger();
const messenger2 = createMessenger();
```

creates two entirely different objects, so changes to one of them do not affect the other.

Comment: Great! I was confusing the outcome of the assignment. I missed that the Object which was assigned was not my function but the Object my function returned, thus, completely different Object. Please forgive me my beginer's query.